# Syntax error in **kwargs in django while trying to print object in shell

Tags: django, powershell, django-class-based-views

I am trying to print the object in the powershell. But I am getting a syntax error.

```
class RestaurantDetailView(DetailView):
     model = Restaurant

     def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs)
     context = super(RestaurantDetail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
     print (context)
     return context
```

the shell is giving me an error:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs)
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: you need a colon at the end of the function declaration e.g. `def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hapens because you forgot the colon and the indentation:

```
class RestaurantDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Restaurant

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(RestaurantDetail, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        print (context)
        return context
```